# Nyquist Plot - Control System Basics

Tags: control-system

If I have a G(s) plot. Can I draw 1+G(s) plot from it? If yes, then please give an example. If no then explain why?

Comment: Shift to the right by 1.

Comment: Thanks @Chu. I was trying to relate with rectangular coordinates and I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment section, just add 1 to every point of the Nyquist plot of \$G(s)\$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Suba Thomas. Can you please explain how its different from rectangular coordinate system? I was shifting it to the left and ended up getting a wrong answer.

Comment: Each point on the Nyquist plot is a complex number \$ \left| G(i w)\right|  \text{$\angle $Arg}(G(i w))\$ in polar coordinates which can be written as \$x+i y\$ in rectangular coordinates. The plot for \$G(s)+1\$ is simply \$x+1+i y\$. Here \$x=\left| G(i w)\right|  \cos (\text{$\angle $Arg} (G(i w)))\$ and \$y=\left| G(i w)\right|  \sin (\text{$\angle $Arg} (G(i w)))\$.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot @Suba Thomas. It is complex plane and not a rectangular plane.

Comment: Please have a look at this problem https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343749/control-system-basics